# Type error: must be real number not Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

my model to code a convolutional neural network is as follow:
Below you will find the code when I use the input examples as a whole.
Thereunder code for minibatches that is working. I do not see the difference!

```
    # model

    def model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, learning_rate = 0.009,
              num_iterations = 100, print_cost = True):
        """
        Implements a three-layer ConvNet in Tensorflow:
        CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> FULLYCONNECTED

        Arguments:
        X_train -- training set, of shape (None, 64, 64, 3)
        Y_train -- test set, of shape (None, n_y = 6)
        X_test -- training set, of shape (None, 64, 64, 3)
        Y_test -- test set, of shape (None, n_y = 6)
        learning_rate -- learning rate of the optimization
        num_epochs -- number of epochs of the optimization loop
        minibatch_size -- size of a minibatch
        print_cost -- True to print the cost every 100 epochs

        Returns:
        train_accuracy -- real number, accuracy on the train set (X_train)
        test_accuracy -- real number, testing accuracy on the test set (X_test)
        parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
        """

        ops.reset_default_graph()                         # to be able to rerun the model without overwriting tf variables
        tf.set_random_seed(1)                             # to keep results consistent (tensorflow seed)
        seed = 3                                          # to keep results consistent (numpy seed)
        (m, n_H0, n_W0, n_C0) = train_x.shape             
        n_y = train_y.shape[1]                            
        costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost

        # Create Placeholders of the correct shape
        ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
        X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0, n_C0, n_y)
        ### END CODE HERE ###

        # Initialize parameters
        ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
        parameters = initialize_parameters()
        ### END CODE HERE ###
        for i in range(0, num_iterations):
            # Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
            ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
            Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
            ### END CODE HERE ###

            # Cost function: Add cost function to tensorflow graph
            ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
            cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)
            ### END CODE HERE ###

            # Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer that minimizes the cost.
            ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
            ### END CODE HERE ###

            # Initialize all the variables globally
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

            # Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
            with tf.Session() as sess:

                # Run the initialization
                sess.run(init)

                # Do the training loop

                _ , temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {X: train_x, Y: train_y})

                ### END CODE HERE ###

            # Print the cost every 5 itterrations
            print("cost =" +str(cost))
            if print_cost == True and i % 5 == 0:
                print ("Cost after num_iterations %i: %f" % (i, cost))
            if print_cost == True and i % 1 == 0:
                costs.append(cost)


            # plot the cost
            plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
            plt.ylabel('cost')
            plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
            plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
            plt.show()

            # Calculate the correct predictions
            predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1)
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict_op, tf.argmax(Y, 1))

            # Calculate accuracy on the test set
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
            print(accuracy)
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: train_x, Y: train_y})
            test_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: test_x, Y: test_y})
            print("Train Accuracy:", train_accuracy)
            print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)

            return train_accuracy, test_accuracy, parameters

However when I call the function model via

    _, _, parameters = model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y)

I run into following error:

    cost =Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-78-8bde5fad21ba> in <module>()
    ----> 1 _, _, parameters = model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y)

    <ipython-input-77-68bdfb51274c> in model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, learning_rate, num_iterations, print_cost)
         73         print("cost =" +str(cost))
         74         if print_cost == True and i % 5 == 0:
    ---> 75             print ("Cost after num_iterations %i: %f" % (i, cost))
         76         if print_cost == True and i % 1 == 0:
         77             costs.append(cost)

    TypeError: must be real number, not Tensor

Can somebody explain me how to resolve this error?
```

**My code with minibatches that is working:**
**Added this code so you can see this is working. I don't see the difference with code above and why code above is not working. Maybe you can help me out. Tnx**

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: model

def model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, learning_rate = 0.009,
          num_epochs = 50, minibatch_size = 64, print_cost = True):
    """
    Implements a three-layer ConvNet in Tensorflow:
    CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> FULLYCONNECTED

    Arguments:
    X_train -- training set, of shape (None, 64, 64, 3)
    Y_train -- test set, of shape (None, n_y = 6)
    X_test -- training set, of shape (None, 64, 64, 3)
    Y_test -- test set, of shape (None, n_y = 6)
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the optimization
    num_epochs -- number of epochs of the optimization loop
    minibatch_size -- size of a minibatch
    print_cost -- True to print the cost every 100 epochs

    Returns:
    train_accuracy -- real number, accuracy on the train set (X_train)
    test_accuracy -- real number, testing accuracy on the test set (X_test)
    parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
    """

    ops.reset_default_graph()                         # to be able to rerun the model without overwriting tf variables
    tf.set_random_seed(1)                             # to keep results consistent (tensorflow seed)
    seed = 3                                          # to keep results consistent (numpy seed)
    (m, n_H0, n_W0, n_C0) = train_x.shape             
    n_y = train_y.shape[1]                            
    costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost

    # Create Placeholders of the correct shape
    ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
    X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0, n_C0, n_y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Initialize parameters
    ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
    parameters = initialize_parameters()
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Forward propagation: Build the forward propagation in the tensorflow graph
    ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
    Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Cost function: Add cost function to tensorflow graph
    ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
    cost = compute_cost(Z3, Y)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Backpropagation: Define the tensorflow optimizer. Use an AdamOptimizer that minimizes the cost.
    ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # Initialize all the variables globally
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Start the session to compute the tensorflow graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Run the initialization
        sess.run(init)

        # Do the training loop
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            #print("m = " + str(m))
            minibatch_cost = 0.
            num_minibatches = int(m / minibatch_size) # number of minibatches of size minibatch_size in the train set
            #print(" minibatch_size =" + str(minibatch_size))
            seed = seed + 1
            minibatches = random_mini_batches(train_x, train_y, minibatch_size, seed)
            #print("minibatch =" + str(minibatch))
            #print("minibatches = " + str(minibatches))

            for minibatch in minibatches:

                # Select a minibatch
                (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch
                # IMPORTANT: The line that runs the graph on a minibatch.
                # Run the session to execute the optimizer and the cost, the feedict should contain a minibatch for (X,Y).
                ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
                _ , temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y})
                ### END CODE HERE ###

                minibatch_cost += temp_cost / num_minibatches

            # Print the cost every 5 epoch
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:
                print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, minibatch_cost))
            if print_cost == True and epoch % 1 == 0:
                costs.append(minibatch_cost)


        # plot the cost
        plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
        plt.ylabel('cost')
        plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
        plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
        plt.show()

        # Calculate the correct predictions
        predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1)
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict_op, tf.argmax(Y, 1))

        # Calculate accuracy on the test set
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        print(accuracy)
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: train_x, Y: train_y})
        test_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: test_x, Y: test_y})
        print("Train Accuracy:", train_accuracy)
        print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)

        return train_accuracy, test_accuracy, parameters
```

**And below the output:**

```
_, _, parameters = model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)

Cost after epoch 0: 1.917929
Cost after epoch 5: 1.506757
Cost after epoch 10: 0.955359
Cost after epoch 15: 0.845802
Cost after epoch 20: 0.701174
Cost after epoch 25: 0.571977
Cost after epoch 30: 0.518435
Cost after epoch 35: 0.495806
Cost after epoch 40: 0.429827
Cost after epoch 45: 0.407291
```

Answer (score 0):

Already line 73 is broken. To print a tensor you need to use `tf.Print`,
but this requires you to add it to your computational graph:

```
print_node = tf.Print(opt.get_slot(var,'m'), [opt.get_slot(var,'m')], 'm')
sess.run([print_node], ...)
```

Comment: I have the same code used with minibatches and there I have no problem. I really don't see why it is not working when I use the input examples as a whole. Line 73 was put by me to see what's really printed as cost. I will edit my question and put the code with minibatches, that code works, maybe you can then tell me why it's not working without minibatches

Comment: Hello Andreas, do you have any idea. I don't see the solution in your previous answer? Above I posted the code with minibatches that is working and you can compare with the code that is not working. I don't see the difference in both codes why the one is working and the other one not? Can you help me further?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutoring site. You keep changing your question radically despite me giving you an answer. If my answer does not work for you then explain why. Don't keep moving the goalposts.

Comment: sorry if I did anything wrong. Sometimes I find the site (stackoverflow) litle complicated to post questions on the right correct way. First I do not know why you are saying I change my question radically? Point is when I want to add a comment I can not add code anymore and also have I think something of arround 500 characters to put a comment. So therefore I edit my question... So all I did was adding code in my question to show what is working and what not. I don't see the difference why in one case it is working and in the other not. I will continue on next comment...

Comment: So the sollution you provided was to print a tensor you need to use tf.print. But why don't I have to use it then in the code were it is working well. So therefore I think something else is wrong but I don't see what? Also when I add your line of code (the solution according you), but I don't know where to put exact that line of code... but anyway then I have the error something like opt. etc... is not defined. @Andreas, anyway thanks for you effort you put in this problem.

Answer (score -1):

problem is solved.
put the itteration `for i in range(0, num_iterations):`

before the line `_ , temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {X: train_x, Y: train_y})`

In stead of before my forward propagation step!